# MongoDB Find by id of object inside array

Tags: mongodb, mongoose, mongodb-query

I have the following Model-Structure

```
[{
  "orders": 
    [{
        "_id": "5f24839133759d4859ef5233",
        "owner": {
            "_id": "5f17fdb08145508a94fc1bda"
        },
     }]
  },
...
]
```

I want to get all objects that have an order with a specific owner id.
I tried `find({"orders.owner._id": "5f17fdb08145508a94fc1bda" })` which just returns an empty array.
Tried many other variations also without dot-notation, but nothing worked.
I'm using mongoose to query the MongoDB database.

EDIT:
These are the Mongoose Schemata used for the collection:

```
const orderPoolShema:mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    orders: [{type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'Order' }]
}, 
{
    timestamps: true
});

const orderShema:mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    owner: {type: mongoose.Types.ObjectId, ref: 'User', require },
}, 
{
    timestamps: true
});

const userShema:mongoose.Schema = new mongoose.Schema({
    firstname: {type: String, required: true},
    lastname: {type: String, required: true}
}, 
{
    timestamps: true
});
```

And this is my Node.js code:

```
OrderPool.find({"orders.owner._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5f17fdb08145508a94fc1bda") })
    .then((orderPools:any) => {
        res.send(orderPools);
    }).catch((err:any) => {
        res.status(500).send({
            message: err.message || "Some error occurred while retrieving orderPools."
        });
    });
```

Any ideas on how to get that query to work are very appreciated.
Thanks for your help.

Comment: Its working as you expected https://mongoplayground.net/p/kKDcbjX-R9P

Comment: you need to convert string id to object type if its object type in document, `find({"orders.owner._id": mongoose.Types.ObjectId("5f17fdb08145508a94fc1bda") })`

Comment: It is still returning an empty array, also when using ObjectId() for the value. Since it's working in the playground, I assume it's a mongoose related issue?